# java.io.notserialzableexception error

Tags: java, serialization

Okay, so I am getting this error. I tried tried making house serialzable, but it still doesn't work? I have no clue what to do at this point. If somebody could help I would appreciate it!

```
ERROR! THREAD NAME: New I/O  worker #1
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: com.rs.game.player.content.construction.House
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.rs.utils.SerializableFilesManager.loadSerializedFile(SerializableFilesManager.java:67)
    at com.rs.utils.SerializableFilesManager.loadPlayer(SerializableFilesManager.java:25)
    at com.rs.net.decoders.LoginPacketsDecoder.decodeWorldLogin(LoginPacketsDecoder.java:184)
    at com.rs.net.decoders.LoginPacketsDecoder.decode(LoginPacketsDecoder.java:51)
    at com.rs.net.ServerChannelHandler.messageReceived(ServerChannelHandler.java:98)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:95)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:91)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:373)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:247)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.rs.game.player.content.construction.House
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.rs.utils.SerializableFilesManager.storeSerializableClass(SerializableFilesManager.java:76)
    at com.rs.utils.SerializableFilesManager.savePlayer(SerializableFilesManager.java:53)
    at com.rs.game.player.Player.realFinish(Player.java:1136)
    at com.rs.game.player.Player.finish(Player.java:1116)
    at com.rs.game.player.Player.finish(Player.java:1088)
    at com.rs.net.ServerChannelHandler.channelDisconnected(ServerChannelHandler.java:76)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:563)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:558)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:399)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:617)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.write0(AbstractNioWorker.java:526)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:427)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:127)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:66)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.writeRequested(SimpleChannelHandler.java:299)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleDownstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:261)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:590)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:581)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:712)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:679)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:246)
    at com.rs.net.Session.write(Session.java:41)
    at com.rs.net.encoders.WorldPacketsEncoder.sendMapRegion(WorldPacketsEncoder.java:880)
    at com.rs.game.player.Player.loadMapRegions(Player.java:696)
    at com.rs.game.player.Player.start(Player.java:613)
    at com.rs.net.decoders.LoginPacketsDecoder.decodeWorldLogin(LoginPacketsDecoder.java:208)
    ... 16 more
```

I am getting that and I have tried nothing so far.

Here is my house.java

```
package com.rs.game.player.content.construction;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.rs.game.DynamicRegion;
import com.rs.game.Region;
import com.rs.game.RegionBuilder;
import com.rs.game.World;
import com.rs.game.WorldObject;
import com.rs.game.WorldTile;
import com.rs.game.item.Item;
import com.rs.game.player.Player;
import com.rs.utils.Logger;

public class House {

    private List<RoomReference> rooms;
    private byte place, look;
    private Player player;

    public House(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
        rooms = player.getRooms();
        place = (byte) player.getPlace(); //desert
    }

    public void refresh(Player player, int[] boundChuncks) {
        player.setForceNextMapLoadRefresh(true);
        constructHouse(boundChuncks, true);
        player.loadMapRegions();
    }

    public void sendFurnitureInterface(Item[] items) {
        player.getPackets().sendItems(396, items);
    }

    public void constructHouse(int[] boundChuncks, boolean buildMode) {
        Logger.log(this, place);
        Object[][][][] data = new Object[4][8][8][];
        for(RoomReference reference : rooms) {
            data[reference.getPlane()][reference.getX()][reference.getY()] =
                new Object[] {reference.getRoom().getChunkX(),  reference.getRoom().getChunkY(),
                    reference.getRotation(), reference.getRoom().isShowRoof()};
        }
        if(!buildMode) { //construct roof
            for(int x = 1; x < 7; x++) {
                skipY: for(int y = 1; y < 7; y++) {
                    for(int plane = 2; plane >= 0; plane--) {
                        if(data[plane][x][y] != null) {
                            boolean hasRoof = (boolean) data[plane][x][y][3];
                            if(hasRoof) {
                                byte rotation = (byte) data[plane][x][y][2];           
                                //TODO find best Roof
                                data[plane+1][x][y] = new Object[] {
                                        Roof.ROOF1.getChunkX(),
                                        Roof.ROOF1.getChunkY(), rotation, true};
                                continue skipY;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(int plane = 0; plane < data.length; plane++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < data[plane].length; x++) {
                for(int y = 0; y < data[plane][x].length; y++) {
                    if(data[plane][x][y] != null)
                        RegionBuilder.copyChunk((int)data[plane][x][y][0] +
                                ((boolean)data[plane][x][y][3] && look >= 4 ? 8 : 0)
                                , (int)data[plane][x][y][1],
                                (boolean)data[plane][x][y][3] ? look % 4 : place
                                , boundChuncks[0]+x, boundChuncks[1]+y, plane,(byte)data[plane][x][y][2]);
                    else if (plane == 0)
                        RegionBuilder.copyChunk(LAND[0], LAND[1], place, boundChuncks[0]+x, boundChuncks[1]+y, plane, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        Region region = World.getRegion(RegionBuilder.getRegionHash(boundChuncks[0]/8, boundChuncks[1]/8));
        List<WorldObject> spawnedObjects = region.getSpawnedObjects();
        if(spawnedObjects != null)
            spawnedObjects.clear();
        List<WorldObject> removedObjects = region.getRemovedObjects();
        if(removedObjects != null)
            removedObjects.clear();
        for(RoomReference reference : rooms) {
            int boundX = reference.getX() * 8;
            int boundY = reference.getY() * 8;
            int boundX1 = boundChuncks[0] * 8;
            int boundY1 = boundChuncks[1] * 8;
            int chunkRotation = region.getRotation(reference.getPlane(), boundX, boundY);
            for(int x = boundX; x < boundX+8; x++) {
                for(int y = boundY; y < boundY+8; y++) {
                    WorldObject[] objects = region.getObjects(reference.getPlane(), x, y);
                    if(objects != null) {
                        for(WorldObject object : objects) {
                            /*
                             * Remove the build hotspots (not 100%)
                             */
                            if(!buildMode && object.getDefinitions().containsOption("Build")) {
                                //object = new WorldObject(object.getId(), object.getType(), (object.getRotation() + chunkRotation) % 4, x + boundChuncks[0]*8,y + boundChuncks[1]*8, reference.getPlane());
                                if (object.getDefinitions().name.equalsIgnoreCase("door hotspot")) {
                                    WorldObject object1 = new WorldObject(getDoorId(), object.getType(), object.getRotation() + 1, object.getX(), object.getY(), reference.getPlane());
                                        World.removeObject(object, true);
                                }

                                else if (object.getDefinitions().name.equalsIgnoreCase("window space")) {
                                    System.out.println(object.getId());
                                } else {
                                    World.removeObject(object, true);
                                }
                                try {
                                    System.out.println("spawning portal");
                                    WorldObject o = new WorldObject(13405, 10, 4, boundChuncks[0]*8 + 35, boundChuncks[1]*8 + 35, 0);
                                    World.spawnObject(o, true);
                                    for (WorldObject o1 : player.getConObjectsToBeLoaded()) {
                                        System.out.println(o1.getDefinitions().getOption(5));
                                        World.spawnObject(o1, true);
                                    }
                                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            /*
                             * Spawn the objects & the hotspots
                             */
                            else if (object.getDefinitions().name.equals("Window")) {
                                object = new WorldObject(getWindowId(), object.getType(), (object.getRotation() + chunkRotation) % 4, x + boundChuncks[0]*8,y + boundChuncks[1]*8, reference.getPlane());
                                World.spawnObject(object, true);
                            }

                            else {
                                try {
                                    for (WorldObject o1 : player.getConObjectsToBeLoaded()) {
                                        World.spawnObject(o1, true);
                                    }
                                    WorldObject o = new WorldObject(13405, 10, 4, boundChuncks[0]*8 + 35, boundChuncks[1]*8 + 35, 0);
                                    World.spawnObject(o, true);
                                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                    System.out.println("Player objects are null");
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void previewRoom(Player player, int[] boundChuncks, RoomReference reference, boolean remove) {
        int boundX = reference.getX() * 8;
        int boundY = reference.getY() * 8;
        Region region = World.getRegion(RegionBuilder.getRegionHash(reference.getRoom().getChunkX()/8, reference.getRoom().getChunkY()/8));
        int boundX2 = (reference.getRoom().getChunkX() - (reference.getRoom().getChunkX() / 8 * 8)) * 8;
        int boundY2 = (reference.getRoom().getChunkY() - (reference.getRoom().getChunkY() / 8 * 8)) * 8;
        DynamicRegion house = (DynamicRegion) World.getRegion(RegionBuilder.getRegionHash(player.getBoundChuncks()[0]/8, player.getBoundChuncks()[1]/8));
        house.getRegionCoords()[reference.getPlane()][reference.getX()][reference.getY()][3] = reference.getRotation();
        for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
                WorldObject[] objects = region.getObjects(reference.getPlane(), boundX2+x, boundY2+y);
                if(objects != null) {
                    for(WorldObject object : objects) {
                        if(object.getDefinitions().containsOption("Build")) {
                            System.out.println("test");
                            int x2 = x;
                            int y2 = y;
                            for (int rotate = 0; rotate < reference.getRotation(); rotate++) {
                                int fakeChunckX = x2;
                                int fakeChunckY = y2;
                                x2 = fakeChunckY;
                                y2 = 7 - fakeChunckX;
                            }
                            object = new WorldObject(object.getId(), object.getType(), (object.getRotation() + reference.getRotation()) % 4, boundX + x2 + boundChuncks[0]*8, boundY + y2 + boundChuncks[1]*8, reference.getPlane());
                            if(remove)
                                player.getPackets().sendDestroyObject(object);
                            else
                                player.getPackets().sendSpawnedObject(object);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getWindowId() {
        switch(place) {
        case 0:
            return 13099;
        case 1:
            return 13115;
        case 2:
            return 0;
        case 3:
            return 0;
        default:
            return 13115;
        }
    }

    public int getDoorId() {
        switch(place) {
        case 0:
            return 13100;
        default:
            return 1058;
        }
    }
    private static final int[] LAND = {233, 632};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe ?

```
public class House implements Serializable { }
```

Comment: and class RoomReference implements Serializable and class Player implements Serializable

Comment: they are alrdy implented serializable

Comment: do i need to implent serializable every class in the package?

Comment: mostly. i don't know your structure, but more-or-less every object moving between server and client needs implements Serializable. The easiest way to figure it out, check 'NotSerializable' exception. if one of your class get this exception, it should implements this interface. especially all of your Entity needs to implement

Comment: furthermore to serialize any kind of objects needs to every property of objects being serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `House` needs to implement the [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface. Currently, it does not:

```
public class House
```

It should be:

```
public class House implements Serializable
```

Since you did not post the source to the other class files you're using, you need to make sure that the classes you're referencing in `House` are also serializable (by defining the above interface). Otherwise, you'll get a similar exception, just not from the `House` class.

Also, you should define your own serialVersionUID. Quoting the above documentation:

> A serializable class can declare its own serialVersionUID explicitly
>   by declaring a field named "serialVersionUID" that must be static,
>   final, and of type long:

```
ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
```

Comment: does it matter if i change the serialversionUID?

Comment: No, a default one will be created by the JVM if you don't define one.